# How to use a variable from a method (inside Try-Catch) in another class?

Tags: java, oop, scope, try-catch

So I'm trying to create a basic RPG userID selection menu using JFrames; I opted to display the ID options using radio buttons. Once the user selects and ID I burp it back using a JOptionPane. All this is done within the MyClass class. When the user makes an ID selection, I read from a .txt file to check against the selection made by the user, because each userID is associated with a Character whose stats are also contained in the .txt file. I was able to break up the multiple lines of the .txt file and store all of the different characteristics as individual Strings. My problem is that now that I want to create another class outside of MyClass that displays said Characteristics using JFrames, I'm having trouble passing variables since the breaking up of the .txt file was done inside a Try-Catch and based on what I have read, these variables are only contained inside the scope of the Try-Catch. This is what the method in the first class I mentioned looks like:

```java
public void checkID()
{

    StringBuilder allInfo=null; //Used to store all the Info
    String line=null; //Used as condition for loop & to generate the String Builder
    String strAll2=null;
    String[] sa=null;
    String[] sb=null;
    String[] sd=null;
    String[] se=null;
    BufferedReader br=null;
     //User Id as a string

    try {



        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("charList.txt"));
        allInfo= new StringBuilder();

        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null)
        { 
            allInfo.append(line + "\n");
        }

        strAll2=allInfo.toString(); //all the info of charList.txt as one StringBuilder
        sa=strAll2.split("\n"); //all the info of charList.txt as a String
        sb=sa[0].split("\t"); //all the info of the first line of the file as individual strings
        sd=sa[1].split("\t"); //all the info of the second line of the file as individual strings
        se=sa[2].split("\t"); //all the info of the third line of the file as individual strings


        if (firstIdButton.isSelected())
        {
            strId=sb[0];
        }
        else
        {
            if (secondIdButton.isSelected())
        {
            strId=sd[0];
        }
            else
            {
                if (thirdIdButton.isSelected())
                {
                    strId=se[0];
                }
            }
        }

        ID = Integer.parseInt(strId);
    }//end of try 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();        

    }//end of catch



    setVisible(false); //Hides Window



}//end of check id method
```

I declared both ID and strId as public int and String, respectively, in the main class Now, I'm looking to do something along the lines of calling ID in another class outside MyClass, and maybe run it through a couple of if-elses to see which Character to display. The problem is that when I instantiate the constructor and try to access the variable, it returns a 0 since the scope of the try-catch doesn't allow me to pass it with the value attained inside the block. I also attempted to make my method return the value of ID but I run into the same problem outside of MyClass

This is where I'm having trouble Implementing it

public class CharacterEditor {

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{ 

    MyClass iw= new MyClass();
    int theID=iw.ID;
    System.out.println(theID);
```

}
}

Comment: I am not quite understanding what your problem is. Did you actually try and do this? Get any errors?

Comment: If you need to annotate the closing brackets then your blocks are _far_ too long.

Comment: Colin-I added more code to show where the issue is. I did try this and I didn't get any runtime errors but the value I get for ID in MyClass doesn't match the value of ID I get in CharacterEditor; I get a '0' in CharacterEditor, meaning it fails to initialize it when I call it this way.

Comment: Commenting is more of a habit I developed but, I agree that the block is a little bit long. If you know a more efficient way of breaking up the code and storing it, it'd be really useful to hear it.

Comment: There are a ton of ways this could be broken up. Also consider ` if `/`else if instead of an extra level of nesting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break up your classes and their responsibilities.  You need *model* classes: classes that represent your game characters, together with classes that do the calculations necessary for your game.  Something like

```
/**
 * A character from the game Toon.
 * @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toon_(role-playing_game)
 */
public class Toon implements Serializable {
    private int muscle;
    private int zip;
    private int smarts;
    private int chutzpah;
    private String name;
    private String species;
    // Constructor, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

You want your view class or classes: your custom `JFrames` and Swing `ActionListeners`. These should do no work on validating ids or reading data from text files.

Your `MyClass` (and that is a name you want to avoid, because in six months you will forget what you were trying to do), shorn of all its `JFrames` and `JButtons` becomes a controller.  It and sibling classes read `Toons` from text files and put them into model classes. It listens for `ActionEvent`s from the view, tries to do what the user wanted, and either updates the model and the view, or reports an error to the view and leaves the model alone.

Answer (score 0):

In your `CharacterEditor` class you're ONLY instantiating your `MyClass` and just that won't invoke `checkID()` and assign proper values to `ID` and `strId` (unless you're invoking it in your constructor)

```
MyClass iw= new MyClass();
iw.checkID(); // MISSING!
int theID=iw.ID;
System.out.println(theID);
```

Without `checkID()` ID would default to 0 (default value given to an uninitialized `int` member variable) and `strId` would remain `null`. Your belief that try-catch is somehow preventing the values you set to be visible at other places is not correct.

Try-catch just like any other Java construct with braces creates its own `Scope` and anything that's declared within a scope wouldn't be visible outside of it. But, if a variable is already present outside of its scope (like ID in your case) any change done to its value within that scope would reflect outside of it as well.

And, it's better to declare member fields as `private` and provide `public` getters (and setters for mutable properties) for them to be accessed in your other classes. Also, like `@DaveNewton` pointed out, use of `else if` is recommended.